# Finding abbreviations that are used before being defined, and those 'double-defined'

Tags: texlive, acronyms

> **Lorem ipsum (LI)** dolor sit amet, consectetur **AE**. Donec in ultricies dui, eu aliquet turpis. In non fermentum arcu. Nunc sodales
>   eros sit amet dictum hendrerit. Integer ut lectus velit. **Lorem ipsum
>   (LI)**  pellentesque lacinia. Nulla mauris elit, **adipiscing elit
>   (AE)** lobortis vitae consequat in, semper et lorem.

I need to find occurrences of abbreviations that are either:

1. used before their first definition, or
2. defined more than once

By 'defining an abbreviation', I mean *manually adding the abbreviation within parentheses directly after the full phrase* (as in Notepad), without any LaTeX methods.

Is there a TeX Live package, or an external script for this?

Comment: without an example document to test it is very hard to guess an answer, what mechanism are you using to define the acronyms?

Comment: I edited the question. No LaTeX mechanism is used to define the abbreviations.

Comment: normally such things are done using a macro that automatically handles different presentation of the first use, rather than doing it by hand and then searching for such use.

Comment: Thanks, I completely agree (e.g., the `glossaries` package). The question is more relevant when LaTeX is not used in the first place!

Comment: if the question is how to search to find such idioms in a plain text file without any tex markup to mark definitions and use of acronyms, I think it's off topic, I don't see how tex can help at all. You will need perl or python or lua or some other regular expression plain text search tool

Comment: Agree. I suggest moving it to Stack Overflow.